# Flutter : smooth video seek to in videoplayer

Tags: android, flutter, video

I want to smooth out the manipulation of the video. I am using video_player: ^2.3.0 and it works smoothly for ios. However, there is a stuttering phenomenon on Android. Can you help me with android issue?

```
setEditVideo(String s3_video_url, String newManipulateType) async {
        Get.find<ConfigController>().onLoading();
        manipulateType = newManipulateType;

        await videoPlayerController?.dispose();

        videoPlayerController = await VideoPlayerController.network(
          s3_video_url,
          videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
        );

        videoPlayerController?.initialize().then((_) {
          videoPlayerController?.play();
        });
        intense = 20;
        // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        Get.find<ConfigController>().offLoading();
        update();
    }

    jumpTimeImageEditVideo(double value) async {
        intense = double.parse(value.toStringAsFixed(2));

        int intIntense = (intense * 100).toInt();

        await videoPlayerController?.seekTo(Duration(milliseconds: intIntense));

        update();
    }
```

I want to smooth out the manipulation of the video.

Comment: Is there a reason for rounding the seek value parameter to 2 floating points? try to use the original value without rounding it

Comment: I've tried without a function that does rounding but I'm still having problems

Comment: well first you dont need to await the seekTo function, and second, what does the update function do?